# Generating dart code from single JSON input

Tags: dart, code-generation

I'm trying to build a dart package which generates API source code from [OData](https://www.odata.org/documentation/) JSON representation file. I tried using `source_gen`, but it appears to generate code based on annotations or existing source code (e.g. JSON serializer generated code for existing class).

Goal: Generate multiple dart codes based on JSON data. E.g.: Say my JSON is:

```json
{
  "user": {
     "income": "Decimal", //Decimal is the type, which I translate it into dart type
  }
}
```

and my generated code would be:

`user.dart`:

```dart
import "package:decimal/decimal.dart";

class User {

   final Decimal age;

   User(this.age);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do is already implemented, when it comes to API description.

You can generate code with classes from `.proto` or swagger `.yaml`/ `.json` files.

1. [Proto file generation for gRPC API](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/dart/quickstart/)

Proto file example:

```proto
message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1;
  int32 page_number = 2;
  int32 result_per_page = 3;
}

message SearchResponse {
 ...
}
```

2. [Swagger rest api code generation from .yml/json files](https://editor.swagger.io)

Look:
[image: img]

Comment: I'm trying to generate API description source code from [OData](https://www.odata.org). I don't think there is a way to generate dart client code from OData description file.